# How to use Kotlin to Write a Y-combinator function?

Tags: kotlin, y-combinator

Can I use Kotlin FP (Lambda, function) to write a Y-combinator function?

```
Y = λf.(λx.f (x x)) (λx.f (x x))
```

In JS:

```js
function Y(f) {
    return (function (g) {
        return g(g);
    })(function (g) {
        return f(function (x) {
            return g(g)(x);
        });
    });
}

var fact = Y(function (rec) {
    return function (n) {
        return n == 0 ? 1 : n * rec(n - 1);
    };
});
```

In Coffee:

```
coffee> Y = (f) -> ((x) -> (x x)) ((x) -> (f ((y) -> ((x x) y))))
[Function]

coffee> fact = Y (f)  ->(n) -> if n==0 then 1 else n*f(n-1)
[Function]

coffee> fact(10)
3628800
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Kotlin, you should introduce an additional interface `G`, Otherwise you will get the `UNCHECKED_CAST` warnings, since Kotlin is a *statically typed* programming language  rather than a dynamic language, for example:

```
typealias X = (Int) -> Int
typealias F = Function1<X, X>
//        v-------------v--- let G reference G recursively
interface G : Function1<G, X>

//  v--- create a G from lazy blocking
fun G(block: (G) -> X) = object : G {
    //                          v--- delegate call `block(g)` like as `g(g)`
    override fun invoke(g: G) = block(g)
}

fun Y(f: F) = (fun(g: G) = g(g))(G { g -> f({ x -> g(g)(x) }) })

val fact = Y({ rec -> { n -> if (n == 0) 1 else n * rec(n - 1) } })
```

Another version cast a `Function1<G, X>` to a `G`, so it should suppress the *UNCHECKED_CAST* warnings, for example:

```
typealias X = (Int) -> Int
typealias F = Function1<X, X>
typealias G = Function1<Any, X>

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
//                                           v--- cast `g` to `G`.
fun Y(f: F) = (fun(g: Function1<G, X>) = g(g as G))({ g -> f { x -> g(g)(x) } })

val fact = Y({ rec -> { n -> if (n == 0) 1 else n * rec(n - 1) } })
```